# Windows 10 black screen, no cursor, no safe mode..... nothing at all

Tags: windows-10

After weeks of ignoring the windows 10 upgrade prompts, last night i decided to give it a go. It took around 4 hours but in the end it appeared to load, i could see the windows screen and set up. As it was very late i closed down the pc in the normal way. Today when i went to open the pc, all i get is a black screen. From switch on i see the manufactures logo [lenovo] then windows symbol and then get the buffering symbol. After about 20 seconds i hear the windows tune. I have a black screen with no mouse cursor. I can not start up in safe mode. I have an all in one pc. I upgraded from windows 7 home edition. I am now totally locked out of my pc and i need this for my work. I`m writing this on a borrowed pc. Microsoft should be held accountable for this, they have totally screwed my pc, does anyone know how to fix this, without having to remove parts etc as im not up to that. Please any help much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try starting in safe mode?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I cant get into safe mode as the screen in completely black after initial windows logo

Comment: @barryov - Do you know how to (manually) boot into Safe Mode with Windows 10?  If this black screen happens when you do boot in Safe Mode, you should edit your question to make that clear.  How the question is written currently indicates that perhaps you have not tried actually using Safe Mode, just your unable to try it, for whatever reason.

Comment: @barryov: If you want to go back to Windows 7, you could try downloading an ISO from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows7 assuming your PC has a sticker with a product key you can use. You'll need to create a bootable DVD or USB drive and change the boot order priority in your BIOS.

Comment: @barryov [How do you start Windows 10 in safe mode?](http://superuser.com/q/948481)

Answer (score -1):

This could be a problem with your graphics drivers. 
They may have not installed correctly. 
If you have some recovery media with your lenovo PC, I would insert this and boot off it. Look for System Restore to roll back the PC into its usable condition and try again. If the problem persists It might be wise to look up a solution from lenovo themselves.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Not sure i have Lenovo recovery disc but will take a look. The pc as been working fine until i installed windows 10 last night