# Where is the windows 10 safe mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, safe-mode

When I press shift+f8 or f8 on boot time windows 10, I can't find safe boot mode. How to boot in safe mode windows 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you start Windows 10 in safe mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/948481/how-do-you-start-windows-10-in-safe-mode)

Comment: Try: Click Restart while holding the shift key down, then  F8 or shift+F8 at the boot screen

Comment: Yes, @MMM that helps well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the command to enable the boot menu in Windows 10;
I do it for all my W10 PCs.

From an admin command prompt enter the command below and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
You should now get the F8 boot menu. 
Start tapping <kbd>F8</kbd> at the BIOS splash screen. 
Be sure to include spaces in the command.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes
```

Comment: At the risk of acting like a five-year-old, I find this confusing.  Does the user “now get the F8 boot menu” immediately after entering the `bcdedit` command, or do they still need to reboot?  Does the `bcdedit` command *give* user the F8 boot menu, or does it only ***enable*** it (so it appears if the user taps the F8 key while rebooting)?

Comment: Reboot, then it works using F8 at the bios screen. Easy peasy.